# c++ auto variable(map) is assigned garbage value

Tags: c++, auto

I tried assigning 'a' variable as follows:

```
for (auto& a : getMap()[1])
```

which assigned a garbage value to `a`. But if I use it after declaring the variable first as shown below, it works normally.

```
auto vv = getMap()[1];
    for (auto& a : vv)
```

Why is it a problem if I use it right away without declaring a variable?

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef struct _mystruct {

} mystruct;

map<int, vector<shared_ptr<mystruct>>> mymap;

void init() {
    vector<shared_ptr<mystruct>> v;
    v.push_back(make_shared<mystruct>(mystruct()));
    mymap[1] = v;
}

map<int, vector<shared_ptr<mystruct>>> getMap() {
    return mymap;
}

int main()
{
    init();

    vector<shared_ptr<mystruct>> v2;
    for (auto& a : getMap()[1]) {
        v2.push_back(a);
    }

    auto vv = getMap()[1];
    for (auto& a : vv) {
        v2.push_back(a);
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really want `getMap` to copy your entire `mymap` every time you call it?  Perhaps you want it to return a reference instead.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime "All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created."  The temporary returned by `getMap()` thus gets destroyed before the body of the `for` loop begins.  valgrind, AddressSanitizer, etc, would help you identify the problem.

Comment: You don't need `typedef` for classes (and `struct` is a `class`) in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until C++17 (details that changed since then don't change the answer) the range based for loop was equivalent to (taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)):

> ```
> {    
>     auto && __range = range_expression ;
>     for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {    
>         range_declaration = *__begin;
>         loop_statement   
>     }    
> }
> ```

Because your `getMap` returns a copy of the map, this:

```
auto&& __range = getMap()[1];
```

Is a reference to an element in the temporary copy of the map that gets destroyed at the end of this statement. `__range` then holds a dangling reference. As anyhow you probably do not want to copy the whole map just to iterate one of its elements, returning a (const) reference instead of a copy from `getMap` will fix the issue.

When you write:

```
auto vv = getMap()[1];
```

Then `vv` is a copy of the vector from the map. Hence, there is no dangling reference in this case.

Comment: Note to future readers: this ought to be fixed in C++23

Comment: @Croolman looking forward to the new pitfalls that this fix will introduce :P

Answer (score 3):

The range based loop is something like this:

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

where `range_expression` is `getMap()[1]` in your code. But the problem is that `getMap()[1]` a temporary variable and its lifetime will be finished after `auto && __range = range_expression ;`. So range loop will be invalid generally.